# Q: Does functionality exist to invoke some promise over an array of arguments and "all"-ify it without boilerplate for-each code?

Tags: bluebird

I was struggling to describe this succintly in the title so I'll paste in my typescript code that achieves what I'm talking about -

```
aggregate<T, A>(args: A[], invokable: (arg: A) => promise<T>): promise<T[]> {
    let allPromises = new Array<promise<T>>();
    for (let arg of args) {
        allPromises.push(invokable(arg));
    }
    return promise.all(allPromises);
}
```

This takes a list of arguments of type A and for each of them invokes some function (which returns a promise which returns type T). Each of these promises are collected into a list which is then all-ified and returned.

My question is, does this function already exist in Bluebird as I'd rather do things properly and use that existing, tested functionality! I had problems getting my head around some of the documentation so I might not have grokked something I should have!

Comment: In Bluebird, you can use `Promise.map()` which combines an iteration of the array with `Promise.all()`.  See examples in the [Bluebird doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is perfectly solvable with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Your code can be turned into:

```
aggregate<T, A>(args: A[], invokable: (arg: A) => promise<T>): promise<T[]> {
    return promise.all(args.map(invocable));
}
```

Comment: Perfect and succinct. Thank you.